# crash on requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, crash

I use this method in my code. When it's deployed on iOS 9.0+ iPhone6 and iOS 7.0+ iPad, it runs well and returns the info I need. But when I use some iOS 10.3.2 iPhone5 to test the code, it just crashes. 
Why? And HOW?

```
void _getIAd()
{
    [[ADClient sharedClient] requestAttributionDetailsWithBlock: 
        ^(NSDictionary *attributionDetails, NSError *error) 
        {
            if(!error) 
            {
                NSError* jError = nil;
                NSData* jData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:attributionDetails options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jError];
                NSString* jString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                UnitySendMessage("Receiver", "SendToLua",[jString UTF8String]);
            }
            return;
        }];
}
```

And my iPhone5 is A1429

Comment: Nothing "just crashes". There is a crash log. Show it.

Comment: Log shows that it crashes when I invoke _getIAd() method. So I dont know why this may crash and how

Comment: No, there's a backtrace that tells you much more.